# java.lang.NullPointerException when creating first android app in OS X 10.9.4

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just download Eclipse JUNO IDE for Android Developers v. 23.0.2.1259578
I am using as a jre:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

but i can't get rid of this error when i build my first android app.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'HelloWorld'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am following this tutorial, but i can't even reach the last step (the problem occurs when i click the Finish button) : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Here the see workspace/.metadata/.log :

```
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'HelloWorld'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.BaseBuilder.abortOnBadSetup(BaseBuilder.java:327)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.build(ResourceManagerBuilder.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: I just made File -> New -> Android Application Project -> Set the application Name -> (set the name) -> next -> next I get this error

Comment: where i can get it from ? i even could create a class

Comment: i am following this tutorial, but i can't even reach the last step: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Comment: @codeMagic - the failure is occurring during the *build process* on the development machine, not during the execution of the poster's code on the Android device.

Comment: yes, when I click Finish button

Comment: @ChrisStratton yeah, missed that at first

Comment: I would upgrade your version of java to a newer version. I am not sure the version of the adk works with jdk 1.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved !

Bring up $ADT_DIR/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini in an editor.  Before the -vmargs line, insert these two lines:

-vm
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Commands/java

Comment: How did this fix things?  I seem to be having the same problem with the very latest version of Eclipse (just starting a new contract job with a client that still uses Eclipse, sigh).

Answer (score 0):

The newer versions of Android require JDK 1.7.  I would try using that.

Comment: same result setting as jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Are you even able to get the project loaded or does eclipse crash?  If you get it loaded to into the project properties > Java Compiler > and then set it to 1.7.  Honestly this isn't my forte it just sounded like something I ran into earlier and setting everything to 1.7 fixed it.

Comment: the project appears in eclipse but empty

Comment: That is very strange.  I'm sorry I wouldn't know anything else to do on this.  I would just make sure you have all the SDK items that you need installed.  Sometimes it's worth it to just start over from scratch on setting up your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I run into such problem recently too. When i create a new Activity, i click the finish or next button in the final step, but nothing happens. When i create a new project that error message pop up   every time. Then i recalled that i **installed SVN on Eclipse** about two month ago. So i **uninstalled SVN** yesterday, everything works out fine now!!! So i think maybe some plugins you installed on your eclipse prevent Android Resource Manager form working properly.

So i suggest you uninstall your plugins and find out whether some of them is wrong.

Hope this would help!

Comment: Thanks but it was a clean distribution of the Eclipse, just installed without extra plugins :-(

Comment: Maybe the workspace isn't new? Old workspace with .project may also affect?